# trigger before insert with if statement within a table

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have another problem with triggers using MySQL.
These two tables namely debt and profile are now connected by a trigger that is solved from my other question here in stackoverflow.

```
CREATE TRIGGER `bal_load_debt` BEFORE INSERT ON  `debt` 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  UPDATE `profile`
  SET `bal` = `bal` + NEW.`amount`
  WHERE `profile`.`id` = NEW.`profile_id`;
END
```

DEBT

```
+--+----------+------+
|ID|PROFILE_ID|AMOUNT|
+--+----------+------+
|1 |1         |500   |
+--+----------+------+
```

PROFILE

```
+--+-------+-----+------+
|ID|BALANCE|LIMIT|STATUS|
+--+-------+-----+------+
|1 |500    |650  |OPEN  |
|2 |300    |500  |OPEN  |
+--+-------+-----+------+
```

My new problem is if the new balance is greater or equal than the limit, the status should be changed to **CLOSE**. I tried modifying the trigger **bal_load_debt** by adding

```
  IF `balance` >= `limit`
      THEN UPDATE `profile`
  SET `status` = 'CLOSE';
  END IF;
```

but results to an error *#1054 Unknown column 'balance' in 'field list'*

I also tried creating another trigger of an after update on profile table but I think the syntax used is not that effective :(

---

The goal is if I add another row at debt like:

```
+--+----------+------+
|ID|PROFILE_ID|AMOUNT|
+--+----------+------+
|1 |1         |500   |
|2 |1         |150   |
+--+----------+------+
```

The profile table should look like this:

```
+--+-------+-----+------+
|ID|BALANCE|LIMIT|STATUS|
+--+-------+-----+------+
|1 |650    |650  |CLOSE |
|2 |300    |500  |OPEN  |
+--+-------+-----+------+
```

I'll be very glad of your helping hands :)

Answer (score 1):

you should have BEFORE UPDATE Trigger over the profile table with the Following Query check

```
IF NEW.balance >= LIMIT THAN
    SET NEW.status = 'CLOSE';
END IF
```

here i am assuming  that LIMIT is the total debt to be paid

Comment: I tried this and have an insert at debt but this error came up: #1054 Unknown column 'limit' in 'field list'

Comment: I think there is an 'override' problem... new error: #1422 - Can's update table 'profile' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.

Comment: i think SET NEW.status = 'CLOSE' Should Work here

Comment: can you write down your complete code here as it seems that you are writing into the wrong trigger this should be part of the BEFORE UPDATE trigger of the Profile table and is there any other trigger which is interacting here ?

Comment: Is it possible to have a variable for `bal` + NEW.`amount` so that we can append an if statement to the current trigger?

Comment: CREATE TRIGGER `limit` BEFORE UPDATE ON  `profile` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN IF NEW.`balance` >=  `limit` THEN SET NEW.`status` =  'CLOSE';

END IF ; END

Comment: I have the trigger bal_load_debt. The code is at the top of this post :)